# Bit mask with 0's in C

Tags: c, bitmask

I need to build a method in C that will return an int, take 3 ints as parameters. The first and second int are the starting and ending bit position. The third int is a 0 or 1 to determine the type of mask.

For example,

```
getMask(2, 6, 1); 
//Set bits 2 to 6 to 1, set all others to zero
```

should set the bits 2 through 6 to a 1 and all other bits to zero.

```
0 0  0  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
```

So `getMask(2, 6, 1)` should return the integer 124.

And `getMask(11, 31, 0)` (set bits 11 to 31 to 0) should return 2047.

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

This is what I have currently:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int getM(int start, int end, int choice) {
    if (choice == 1){
       return ~(~0 << (end - start + 1)) << (start);
    }
    else if (choice == 0){
       return ~(~1 << (end - start + 1)) << (start);
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}
```

It works when I the choice is 1, but for 0 I am completely lost.

I currently get -2048 for getMask(11, 31, 0).

I know I can use ands and ors, but I cannot figure out how to use them the way I am doing this.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more about asking questions that will attract quality answers.  You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49574399/edit) to include more information.  What output do you get when `choice==0`?

Comment: You *can't* use `int` for this compatibly - suggest you use `uint32_t`.

Comment: Thank you! I will edit it to say this, but I currently get -2048 for getMask(11, 31, 0)

Comment: Also the `getMask(11, 31, 0)` - shouldn't it just be the inverse of `getMask(11, 31, 1)` - i.e. just invert the return value *once* with `~`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@AnttiHaapala is correct: `choice==0` is just the bitwise negation of `choice==1` for the same `start` and `end`.  Therefore (as an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int getM(int start, int end, int choice) {
    if (choice == 1){
       return ~(~0 << (end - start + 1)) << (start);
    }
    else if (choice == 0){
       return ~getM(start, end, 1); /* Just use what you have, but ~ it */
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}

int main() {
    printf("2 6 1 %d\n", getM(2,6,1));
    printf("11 31 0 %d\n", getM(11,31,0));
}
```